# Copy GCS file to another directory in same bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to copy few files in my GCS bucket to another folder in the same bucket like:

**Folder structure**

```
Bucket
 -File1.jpg
 -File2.jpg
 -File3.jpg
 -Folder1
```

I want to Copy File1 and File2 from this bucket to Folder1 using **python**.

**Expected Folder structure**

```
Bucket
 -File1.jpg
 -File2.jpg
 -File3.jpg
 -Folder1
   -File1.jpg
   -File2.jpg
```

Comment: Where's the problem? Can you show any code you have so far? Any error you are getting?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it
It's working

```
    from google.cloud import storage
    import google.auth
    from google.oauth2 import service_account 
    
    def copyblob(filename):    
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename="cred.json",scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]) 
        gcs_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
            
        bucket_name='bucket1'
        blob_name=filename
        destination_bucket_name='bucket1'
        destination_blob_name='Folder1/'+filename
        source_bucket = gcs_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
        destination_bucket = gcs_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)
        print(destination_bucket)
        blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
               source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
            )
        
        print(
            "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
                source_blob.name,
                source_bucket.name,
                blob_copy.name,
                destination_bucket.name,))
        
          
if __name__=='__main__':
    filee='File1.jpg'
    copyblob(filee)
```